# Result of axios api call ignored

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm making a react and node application.
I managed to make the login and the signup but I have a little problem.
The authentification is managed by jwt with a token in local storage.

What I want to do is display the infos of my user which is logged in.
So, to do that I use this

```
const fetchUserData = async () => {
    try {
        const user = await API.getUser();
        setUser(user.data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserData()
}, [])
```

the getUser function is simply an axios call :

```
getUser: function () {
    return axios.get(
        `/currentUser`,
        {
            headers: headers
        }
    )
}
```

The controller connected to it return my user thanks to my middleware.

```
 app.get('/currentUser', auth, (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({_id: req.user.id}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(user);
    })
})
```

Unfortunately when I'm logging in, I can see my token but my user in my state is still null.

I saw in another post that's because my useEffect first runs on mount of component and don't call well my getUser function. I thought that I needed to add user in the second argument of my useEffect in order to call again the useEffect but it doesn't change anything.

Oh and I noticed that after the login, I only have my user completed in my state if I refresh the page.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I am not sure why your state is not updated. It doesn't seem to be an issue with the code you've posted as far as i can tell. Just a few notes aside; 1. You should consider just letting cookies keep track of your JWT as saving it in localStorage opens you up to XSS attacks. You also should add a return to your res.send and res.json statements as they will both be triggered in case of an error.

Comment: okay, I found out the origin ! It's my middleware. When I'm just logged in I can see my token in my local storage but with axios when i set it in my headers like this, const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem("token")
},

It is null if I don't refresh on this line req.headers['authorization']

Comment: I'm happy you figured it out :)